# New intent in LUIS for multi turn dialogs

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, dispatch

I am going to create a multi-turn dialog. I didn't get how it should be connected with LUIS models. I checked out documentation, but there are samples with only one turn dialogs. Also, I use Virtual Assistant template.
I want to do something like this.

> User: I want to book a flight
>
> Bot: What is the destination?
>
> User: London
>
> Bot: When?
>
> User: 21st of September.
>
> Bot: The ticket was bought.

The questions are what happens on the second step? Should I check out dispatcher? Should I add all possible phrases for all steps inside the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General LUIS stuff**

For your LUIS model you will need your intents - `BookFlight` and `None`. Under your `BookFlight` intent you will have your `Utterances` - all the phrases you want to be able to trigger the `BookFlight` intent.

```
MyLuisApp
--BookFlight
----I want to book a flight
----Book a flight
----I need a plane ticket
----etc
--None
----Utterances that don't match any of your intents
```

The none intent is VERY important as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent#none-intent-is-fallback-for-app).

---

**Adding this functionality to a new bot or the core bot template**

There are a couple different samples provided on how you could achieve this, but the best way is using Dialogs. What you want is a [Waterfall Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). Inside this Dialog you can define each stage in the waterfall e.g. Ask for destination, ask for date etc.

In order to trigger the BookFlight waterfall you would have a MainDialog that handled every request, and checks with the LUIS dispatcher [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#use-the-dispatch-model) and [link2](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch) to find out the users intent as per [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L77). If the intent is `BookFlight` then you would start the BookFlightDialog which contains the book flight waterfall.

```
...
// Check dispatch result
var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);
var intent = dispatchResult.TopIntent().intent;

if (intent == "BookFlight")
{
    // Start BookFlightDialog
    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookFlightDialog));
}
```

---

**General Waterfall Dialog stuff**

You'd define your steps as something like:

```
var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
{
    AskDestinationAsync,
    AskDepartureDateAsync,
    ConfirmStepAsync,
    FinishDialogAsync,
};
```

For your scenario there is actually a sample that has already been created with the BookFlight intent available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot). There is a full guide on how to get this setup and working in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). So you can test to see how everything works then modify it as you need.

Other interesting links:

- [Custom prompt sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/44.prompt-users-for-input/Bots/CustomPromptBot.cs) - roll your own.
- [Multi-turn sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs) - waterfall dialog.

---

**Virtual Assistant stuff**

Once you understand how the above works you will be able to modify the Virtual Assistant template to handle the BookFlight intent by taking the following actions:

- Adding a BookFlight intent to your existing LUIS **DISPATCH** app that is connected to your VA template.
- Adding utterances to the BookFlight intent.
- Save and train your LUIS app.
- Publish your LUIS app.
- Running the update_cognitive_models.ps1 script as per **step 3** of the instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/customizeassistant.md#add-an-additional-knowledgebase) which will pull down the changes (your new intent and utterances).

  - `.\Deployment\Scripts\update_cognitive_models.ps1 -RemoteToLocal`

    - **NOTE:** This command must be run using [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.2.1) and from the root of your project Directory, i.e. inside your Virtual Assistant folder.

The result of running this script should be a bunch of files created locally, as well as the `DispatchLuis.cs` file being updated to include your new intent. You should also check the `Summary.html` file that is created to see that your new intent is there. You will now have to update the VA code to actually do something when your new intent is triggered - add another if/case statement inside the `RouteAsync` method of the `MainDialog.cs` file - see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Template/VA/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L100) for an example.

Something like this:

```
MainDialog.cs

protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Call to dispatch to get intent

    if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.bookflight)
    {
        // Start BookFlightDialog
        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookFlightDialog));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How did you go @Dmitresky?

Comment: I have created the dialog. Thank you! But I don't understand what happens on the second step. Does the request go to dispatcher?

Comment: Are you asking about the second and subsequent steps in the waterfall dialog?

Comment: @Dmitresky so how it works is that a user will say something like "I want to book a flight". This text will be sent off to LUIS, where it will match the "Book Flight" intent. In the code when the "Book Flight" intent is matched then the `BookFlightDialog` is started. The user will go through the various steps in the dialog, once all of the steps have been completed, then the `BookFlightDialog` will be ended and the user will be returned to the `MainDialog` and their input will be started to be processed by LUIS again to determine the intent. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: yes, thank you Matt! But what about Cancel? I mean if user changes his mind and doesn't want to continue a dialog. Cancel is another intent, isn't it? What is pipeline in this case?

Comment: If you are using the Virtual Assistant Template then cancelling is built in. You can test this by typing “cancel” when the bot starts up and you should get something like “there is nothing to cancel” back as the message. But when you are in a dialog flow you will see a cancel confirmation message. The flow for this is that the code will go to the OnInterrupt method in MainDialog.cs before it goes to the code for the active dialog, thus the user will be able to cancel rather than having their input swallowed by your inner dialog.

Comment: MainDialog.cs inherits from [RouterDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/529d2cc05f6f0fda68380347d95c0eb042b4c7fa/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotSample/EnterpriseBotSample/Dialogs/Shared/RouterDialog.cs) which inherits from [InterruptableDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/529d2cc05f6f0fda68380347d95c0eb042b4c7fa/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotSample/EnterpriseBotSample/Dialogs/Shared/InterruptableDialog.cs), `OnInterruptDialogAsync` is the method you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you again Matt! You really helped me!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.