# Microsoft LUIS: coreference

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm looking for solution to be able to manage [coreference](https://medium.com/huggingface/state-of-the-art-neural-coreference-resolution-for-chatbots-3302365dcf30) into conversation with Microsoft LUIS and Microsoft Bot Framework SDK.

Is there any existing solution into Microsoft's environment ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no multi-turn solution yet in LUIS itself, however if you are integrating with the Bot Framework, you can use LUIS and BF Dialogs to implement an multi-turn solution. See this other [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682939/new-intent-in-luis-for-multi-turn-dialogs).

Comment: Thank you @Zeryth for your reply. But I'm not sure to understand how multi-turn will manage the coreference concept because it's more a NLU issue instead of dialog conception. For example, if my bot say "It's Barak Obama, former president of USA" and the user reply "Oh cool, how old is he ?": "he" is a coreference to "Barak Obama".

Comment: I've asked the LUIS team directly if they can confirm best practices with the tools that we have currently, or if they plan unrolling anything with coreferences in the future. I'll let you know if they have a better idea of how to handle such cases.